# Can't install IE 9 on Windows 7 OS

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, internet-explorer-9

My OS is Windows 7 Home Premium, 64 bit.

I had download IE9 from http://Windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie.
which didn't show any error messages but just not run.

When I download IE9 beta version, it works.
does anyone has same situation and how did you solve it?

Comment: Did you uninstalled IE9 Beta before installing IE9 release?

Comment: Did you try re-downloading the installer and running it again?

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall all versions of IE9 from the system.

Then download and run the appropriate Microsoft SUR tool

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821

Reboot and try installing IE9 again.

Be sure to select the proper version of both of these programs.

EDIT:

I just tried to install IE9 on my W7 64bit system and it would not install, it stalled with no errors, tried 3 times, stalled during download phase and no errors, had to kill it in task manager.

What I did to get it installed.

Performed a clean boot using msconfig, use step 1 and 2 in the article below and restart the pc and install IE9, if IE installs, reboot again, then use msconfig again to revert the changes you made earlier, restart one last time.

> Step 1: Start the System Configuration Utility
>   Click Start, type msconfig in the Start Search box, and then press ENTER.
>
> If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a confirmation, type the password, or provide confirmation.
>
> Step 2: Configure Selective Startup options
>
> In the System Configuration Utility dialog box, click Selective Startup on the General tab.
>
> Click to clear the Load Startup Items check box.
>
> Click the Services tab.
>
> Click to select the Hide All Microsoft Services check box.
>
> Click Disable All, and then click OK.
>
> When you are prompted, click Restart.

.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/331796/en-us

.